# adding canvas into a LinearLayout

Tags: android, canvas, android-linearlayout, compass-geolocation

I am programming a compass android app
now I'm facing a problem that I want to add a canvas in the main XML file with a back button i designed to let the user go back to the menu

I used the `addview()` try to add the canvas compass into the main.xml but still error
the error was an NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION on "mainLayout.addView(compassView);" at the MAIN.JAVA code

here is my code

**MAIN.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    compassView = new MyCompassView(this);
    setContentView(compassView);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.compasslayout);
    LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    compassView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);

    mainLayout.addView(compassView);
```

**MyCompassView.java**

```
public class MyCompassView extends View {

  private Paint paint;
  private float position = 0;

  public MyCompassView(Context context) {
      super(context);

      init();
  }

  private void init() {
      paint = new Paint();
      paint.setAntiAlias(true);
      paint.setTextSize(25);
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);    
      paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      paint.setStrokeMiter(position);
  }
```

**XML FILE**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Compass" >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:id="@+id/compasslayout">

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttona"
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:background="@drawable/b_select" />

     </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="10dp">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me, I stuck in this already a day and I can't continue without finish this task

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
compassView = new MyCompassView(this);
setContentView(compassView);
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.compasslayout);
```

You are setting a new `MyCompassView` as the content view instead of your XML file. This means that when you call `findViewById()`, the View of id `R.id.compasslayout` cannot be found. Your call to `setContentView()` should be `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)`.

Comment: i had changed the setContentView(R.layout.mylayout) as you said but it still NULLPOINTER on the mainLayout.addView(compassView); the original layout file of this app is R.layout.compass